Is there a way to customize the available Maven goals in the Netbeans Language Server for VS Code?
I'm using the Apache NetBeans Language Server Extension for VS Code, with no other Java extensions enabled. When right-clicking on a project, these Maven goals are available: [Compile Project, Clean Project, Test Project]
Is there a way to customize these goals/phases? I've gone through the documentation and I don't see anything about being able to customize these.

You can start a bounty for this. Looks like an interesting question. It will be worth the effort. :D

There is no native support for this in the Netbeans Language Server for VSCode for now.However you can use VSCode tasks to perform customized command or additional Maven/VSCode plugins to add customized goals.
